# Write a function gets number of squares and will return how many integer numbers are used as square

Tags: c, algorithm, math

> Write a function getNumberOfSquares(int n) (C) / get_number_of_squares that will return how many integer (starting from 1, 2...) numbers raised to power of 2 and then summed up are less than some number given as a parameter.
> e.g 1: For n = 6 result should be 2 because 1^2 + 2^2 = 1 + 4 = 5 and 5 < 6 E.g 2: For n = 15 result should be 3 because 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 1 + 4 + 9 = 14 and 14 < 15

For the function above I wrote a program but the test program gave an error that is when input is `getNumberOfSquares(100000)` function should return 66 but mine returns 403.

Here is my solution:

```
int getNumberOfSquares(int n){

    int sum=0;
    int limit=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n && n>sum; ++i)
    {
        sum += i*i;
        ++limit;
        if(sum>=n){
            sum -= i*i;
            --limit;
        }
    }
    return limit;
}
```

Comment: Try to figure out the smallest possible input that gives the wrong result. Then use common debugging techniques (like using an actual debugger to step through the code) to attempt to figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that an integer is 32 bits on your system, `i*i` will overflow once it reaches a value of 65536.  That causes the inaccuracies.

However it shouldn't actually reach that point, since you continue to check values of `i` even after the value of `sum` exceeds `n`.  You should break out of the loop when you reach that point.

```
int getNumberOfSquares(int n){

    int sum=0;
    int limit=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (sum + i*i >= n) {
            return limit;
        }
        sum += i*i;
        ++limit;
    }
    return limit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate or give me some sources to explain this overflowing stuff? Why does i*i operation becomes overflowed?

Comment: The largest number that can fit in a 32 bit signed integer is 2147483647, or 2^31-1.  When a calculation would exceed that, formally you have undefined behavior but in practice that typically means the value "wraps around".

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the biggest `i` such that `sum < n`. So this should be the only condition breaking the loop. You don't need to check even that `i < n`.

Now the problem of your code is that you modify `sum` when it gets big enough to break the loop, making it again less than `n`. So if `sum < n` was your only condition you would have had an infinite loop. But since you have the `i < n` condition, the program keep adding and subtracting `i*i` to `sum` until `i < n`.

If `n` is small enough, adding and subtracting `i*i` doesn't change `sum` and when the loop breaks you get your result.

But if `i` can grow big enough to make sum greater than the greatest `int` you can have, `sum` overflows and becomes a meaningless value.

The solution is to eliminate the condition `if(sum>=n){}`.

Removing the condition will reveal that `limit` is like `i`, so you can even use `i` as returned value.

And keeping in mind that you don't need the condition `i < n`, your function becomes

```
int getNumberOfSquares(int n) {

    int i, sum = 0;

    for(i = 1; sum < n; ++i) {
        
        sum += i*i;
    }
    
    return i-2;
}
```

Returning `i-2` because the `i` making `sum > n` was already 1 more than the value you wanted to return and then before `sum > n` is checked, the`for` increments `i`.